# npm does not work behind corporate proxy and launched from apm

Tags: node.js, git, atom-editor

I'm having an issue with npm behind a proxy.

`npm install` fails because npm can not git clone when launched from apm, which is weird because same command line out of apm works.

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true fetch -a origin
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (Unknown host.)
```

.npmrc content

```
proxy=http://proxy-xxx:8080
http-proxy=http://proxy-xxx:8080
https-proxy=http://proxy-xxx:8080
```

.gitconfig content

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
[http]
    proxy = proxy-xxx:8080
```

Seems it comes from git URL, which is weird because same command works when launched manually.

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOME environment has been set to `%USERPROFILE%\.atom\.node-gyp` during plugin installation. It differs obviously from usual git execution.
So, I bypassed the problem by putting .gitconfig there which describes HTTPS proxy setting and schema-replacement rule.

Cheers,
Yann