# Ionic app creation gets stuck at “ionic start app_name tabs”

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework, facing below issue while creating first app.
**i am working behind corporate proxy
-> command executed “ionic start hello_ionic tabs”
Error Message :
? The directory hello_ionic contains file(s) that could conflict. Would you like to overwrite the directory with this new project? Yes
√ Creating directory .\hello_ionic - done!
√ Downloading and extracting tabs starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes
√ Personalizing ionic.config.json and package.json - done!

```
ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
√ Downloading integration cordova - done!
√ Copying integrations files to project - done!
[OK] Added cordova integration!
```

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.
    IONIC DEVAPP *
Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app
    Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
    LiveReload for instant style and JS updates
️   –>Install DevApp:

```
npm i

Running command
```

ionic start stuck at “npm i”.

please help me in resolving this issue.

->output of “npm info”

```
{ name: ‘hello_ionic’,
description: ‘a’,
‘dist-tags’: { latest: ‘1.0.0’ },
versions: [ ‘1.0.0’ ],
maintainers: [ ‘gboog andersonthomas603@gmail.com’ ],
time:
{ modified: ‘2017-04-19T13:42:30.205Z’,
created: ‘2017-04-19T13:42:30.205Z’,
‘1.0.0’: ‘2017-04-19T13:42:30.205Z’ },
homepage: ‘https://github.com/WebGExecutive/app#readme’,
keywords: [ ‘sss’ ],
repository:
{ type: ‘git’,
url: ‘git+https://github.com/WebGExecutive/app.git’ },
author: ‘Griffin Blotner’,
bugs: { url: ‘https://github.com/WebGExecutive/app/issues’ },
license: ‘ISC’,
readmeFilename: ‘’,
version: ‘1.0.0’,
main: ‘index.js’,
scripts: { test: ‘s’ },
dist:
{ shasum: ‘73936188b9f38359107be3fce56da2643d195a89’,
tarball: ‘https://registry.npmjs.org/appapp/-/appapp-1.0.0.tgz’ },
directories: {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

npm i does not works with Proxy.
You can refer to following links -

[npm does not work behind corporate proxy and launched from apm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493671/npm-does-not-work-behind-corporate-proxy-and-launched-from-apm)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-npm-install-the-command-behind-corporate-proxy-server/